# Broadcast Sender and Receiver pair

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

On one file I am sending the broardcast.

```
Intent Message1 = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
Message1.putExtra("hello", false);
sendBroadcast(Message1);
```

On the receiver Side, I have

```
myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtra.equals("hello") {
            [...]
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

The key is the receiever has to have intent's Extra match to the broadcaster's "hello" in order to proceed.  Can I do like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why put extra and not using intent filter + action (which is the main idea of receivers)?

I would to something like this

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("hello"); // More complicated action maybe?
yourContext.registerReceiver(new myreceiver(), filter);
```

and in onReceive:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals("hello")) 
    {
        // go on....
    }
 }
```